# Canonical representation of a BigDecimal

Tags: java, math, equals, bigdecimal, canonicalization

What is the simplest way to reduce a Java [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) containing an arbitrary value to a canonical form so that two `BigDecimal`'s representing the same number will compare equal using the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method?

I am parsing my numbers from arbitrary strings using code like this:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(string1, MathContext.DECIMAL64);
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(string2, MathContext.DECIMAL64);
```

Since (`string1`, `string2`) are arbitrary, they could be, e.g., (`"1"`, `"1.0000"`) or (`"-32.5"`, `"1981"`)...

What I'm looking for is the simplest (shortest/cleanest code) implementation of the method canonicalize for which the above assertion

```
assert x.compareTo(y) != 0 ||
    (canonicalize(x).equals(canonicalize(y)) && 
     x.compareTo(canonicalize(x)) == 0 && y.compareTo(canonicalize(y)) == 0);
```

will succeed...:

```
public static BigDecimal canonicalize(BigDecimal b) {
    // TODO:
}
```

Comment: Why would you need this instead of simply using `compareTo`?

Comment: Can't you use `x.setScale(y.scale())`?

Comment: @Keppil, I'm looking at the docs now and it looks like you're right: ["
Returns a `BigDecimal` whose scale is the specified value, and whose value is numerically equal to this `BigDecimal`'s."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-)

Comment: You might run into rounding issues though. This might be a problem or might not, I'm not sure about the use case here.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if two `BigDecimal`s are equal regardless of scale, just use `.compareTo()`

```
public static boolean bigDecimalEquals(BigDecimal b1, BigDecimal b2) {
    return b1.compareTo(b1) == 0;
}
```

It specifically recommends this [in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal))

> Two BigDecimal objects that are equal in value but have a different scale (like 2.0 and 2.00) are considered equal by this method. This method is provided in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean comparison operators (<, ==, >, >=, !=, <=).

---

If you actually want to convert the `BigDecimal` so that `.equals()` will work, just use the [`setScale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) method.

Comment: accepted for the reference to `setScale()` as mentioned by @Keppil earlier. It should be obvious from my original post that I know about `compareTo()` and didn't require that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`stripTrailingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros--). This returns an equivalent `BigDecimal` with the scale minimized and is the simplest way to get a canonical representation. It's better than `setScale()` because it avoids any issues with rounding.